# django rest framework create nested objects "Models" by POST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying POST a new a Nested Object, the problem is just create the "top" object (Playlist), but don't create the "ChannelItem"...

My Models:

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    provider = models.IntegerField()
    channel_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    channel_version = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500)


class ChannelItem(models.Model):
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(Playlist, editable=False, related_name='channelitems')
    content_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content_version = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
```

My Serializer:

```
class ChannelItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChannelItem
        fields = ('content_id', 'content_version')
        exclude = ('id')
        depth = 1


class PlaylistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Playlist
        fields = ('id', 'provider', 'channel_id', 'channel_version', 'start', 
                  'url', 'channelitems')
        depth = 2

channelitems = ChannelItemSerializer()
```

I use the curl to post the following data :

```
'{"provider":125,"channel_id":"xyz", "channel_version":"xsqt", 
"start":"2012-12-17T11:04:35","url":"http://192.168.1.83:8080/maaaaa",
"channelitems":[{"content_id":"0.flv", "content_version":"ss"},
{"content_id":"1.flv","content_version":"ss"}]}' http://localhost:8000/playlist_scheduler/playlists/
```

I receive the message:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 CREATED
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 17 Dec 2012 20:12:54 GMT
Server: 0.0.0.0

{"id": 25, "provider": 125, "channel_id": "xyz", "channel_version": "xsqt",
"start":"2012-12-17T11:04:35", "url": "http://localhost:8080/something",
"channelitems": []}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nested representations [do not currently support read-write](http://tomchristie.github.io/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/serializers.html#dealing-with-nested-objects), and should instead be read-only.

You should probably look into using a flat representation instead, using pk or hyperlinked relations.

If you need the nested representation, you may want to consider having two separate endpoints - a flat writable endpoint, and a nested read-only endpoint.

Comment: I've seen the term flat representation also used several times in the REST framework documentation, but can you give an example of what this means exactly?  I fully understand the nested serializers, but I need to read-write, not just read.  My options it seems are to flatten out the representation, or to write my own custom RelatedField?

Comment: @avances123 it seems so! see: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/tests/test_relations_nested.py

Comment: @fjsj the link you posted is returning 404. Can anyone post a link that shows where/how it says to do this?

Comment: @JamesBerlin it seems the file was moved. here is the current link: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/f7de442ef4dc906d85249182d4a977b816873cec/tests/test_relations_nested.py

but those tests are commented out. don't know why.

Comment: @TomChristie is nested representation supported now? Could you provide a link on how to use it?

Comment: @TomChristie, I have similar question to JamesBerlin . Do we have progress on nested resources?

Comment: No - the expected behavior is too ambiguous so we force the user to declare the create/update methods explicitly. See here... http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: @TomChristie Hi!, I'm trying to do it as it says in the documentation(providing my create method) but when i do it with the manage.py shell it works ok, but when I POST to my ListCreateAPIView it happens the same problem as stated in this post, what can be happening? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

If someone needs a quick-and-dirty solution for that, I came up with this one I'll be temporary using in a project:

```
class NestedManyToManyField(serializers.WritableField):
    def to_native(self, value):
        serializer = self.Meta.serializer(value.all(), many=True, context=self.context)
        return serializer.data
    def from_native(self, data):
        serializer = self.Meta.serializer(data=data, many=True, context=self.context)
        serializer.is_valid()
        serializer.save()
        return serializer.object
    class Meta:
        serializer = None
```

Then create your own subclass of `NestedManyToManyField`:

```
class TopicNestedSerializer(NestedManyToManyField):
    class Meta:
        serializer = MyOriginalSerializer
```

An example of `MyOriginalSerializer`:

```
class MyOriginalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'title',)
```

This works fine for me so far. But be aware there are clean fixes coming:

- https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/960
- https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/817

Answer (score 3):

after a long effort I made a first version that funcinasse ...
I believe that with some improvement could be included within the ModelSerializer

```
class ChannelItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ChannelItem
        fields = ('id', 'content_id', 'content_version')

    def field_from_native(self, data, files, field_name, into):
        try:
            if self._use_files:
                _files = files[field_name]
            else:
                _data = data[field_name]
        except KeyError:
            if getattr(self, 'default', None):
                _data = self.default
            else:
                if getattr(self, 'required', None):
                    raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'])
                return

        if type(_data) is list:
            into[field_name] = [] 
            for item in _data:
                into[field_name].append(self._custom_from_native(item))
        else:
            into[field_name] = self._custom_from_native(_data)


    def _custom_from_native(self, data):
        self._errors = {}
        if data is not None:
            attrs = self.restore_fields(data, None)
            attrs = self.perform_validation(attrs)
        else:
            self._errors['non_field_errors'] = ['No input provided']

        if not self._errors:
            return self.restore_object(attrs, instance=getattr(self, 'object', None))




class PlaylistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Playlist
        fields = ('id', 'provider', 'channel_id', 'channel_version', 'start', 'url', 'channel_items')
        depth = 1

    channel_items = ChannelItemSerializer()

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        self.foreign_data = {}

        for (obj, model) in self.opts.model._meta.get_all_related_objects_with_model():
            field_name = obj.field.related_query_name()
            if field_name in attrs:
                self.foreign_data[field_name] = attrs.pop(field_name)


        return super(PlaylistSerializer, self).restore_object(attrs, instance)

    def save(self, save_m2m=True):
        super(PlaylistSerializer, self).save(save_m2m)

        if getattr(self, 'foreign_data', None):
            for accessor_name, object_list in self.foreign_data.items():
                setattr(self.object, accessor_name, object_list)
            self.foreign_data = {}

        return self.object
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I have a hybrid workaround that I'm OK with.  Namely, create a view that has:

- the ManyToMany field in its un-nested serializer form
- alias the nested ManyToMany field into a variable with `_objs` as the suffix and specify it as as read only
- when you `PUT` back to the server reconcile the two aliased fields and store the result in the un-nested serializer field

e.g.

```
class MSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    foo_objs = TempSensorSerializer(source='foos', many=True, allow_add_remove=True,required=False,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = M
        fields = ('url', 'foos', 'foo_objs')
```

I don't love this solution, but it beats trying to separately query and collate the nested fields after retrieving the initial container.