# How to customize Serializer in django-rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to customize serializer so I can post data of `challenged_to` field when I create (post) challenge.

I have model class:

```
class Challenge(models.Model):
    """
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    app = models.ForeignKey(App)
    challenged_to = models.ManyToManyField(Student, through='ChallengeStudents')
    challenged_by = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='challenge_created_by')
    points = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%d - %s" % (self.id, self.name)
```

And ChallengeStudents class:

```
class ChallengeStudents(models.Model):
    """
    """

    CHALLENGE_STATUS_CHOICES = (
            (1, 'Pending'),
            (2, 'Accepted'),
            (3, 'Rejected'),
    )
    challenge = models.ForeignKey(Challenge)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=1, choices=CHALLENGE_STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.challenge, self.student)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Challenged students"
```

And serializer:

```
class ChallengeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """
    """
    #challenged_to = want to custmize it

    class Meta:
        model = Challenge
```

In this case I gets a form to post data of Challenge model except challenged_to field.
How can I customize it so that I can get challenged_to field as well in form.

Comment: DRF doesn't support nested writes although I believe there's a way using the HyperlinkedRelatedField or by writing your own custom field. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164404/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164404/)