# Django Serializers many to many relationship

Tags: django, angularjs, many-to-many

I am working in a small project using Angularjs and Django. I have two different models with its corresponding end points.

```
class Skills(models.Model):
    skills = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.skills



  class Project(models.Model):
...
    required_skills = models.ManyToManyField(
            Skills, verbose_name="list of skills")
..
```

This is a copy of my skills end point

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "skills": "Css"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "skills": "HTML5"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "skills": "Java"
    }
]
```

On the front page I have a form that uses $http.post service to send data to the database. When I project is created, it might require one skill or multiple skills. Here is where my confusion come, I can store I foreign key by sending the pk which in this case is id. However, since I am dealing with a many to many relationship, I can not figure out what is the best way to proceed. I have read the documentation and some online resources with any success. Also, the form has an dropdown menu with the list of skills.I got this values using $http.get. Please anyone has any idea of how to solve this issue?

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/
[Serializing ManyToMany in Django Rest Framework (2.3.5) throws ValueError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935638/serializing-manytomany-in-django-rest-framework-2-3-5-throws-valueerror)

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with a similar situation recently.
The way I approached the problem was to override the create method in the serializer to look like:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    serviceOffers_data = validated_data.pop('serviceOffers')

    def extract_id(s):
      return s['id']

    clientfile = Clientfile.objects.create(**validated_data)
    clientfile.serviceOffers.add(*ServiceOffer.objects.filter(id__in=map(extract_id, serviceOffers_data)))

    return clientfile
```

My POST data looks like so:

```
{
    name: 'Hello',
    serviceOffers: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'service offer 1'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'service offer 2'
        }
    ]
}
```

The extract_id function isn't mandatory. I used it because of the structure of the incoming Json. You could as well just send the list of pk's and get rid of extract_ids.