# Creating a nested resource having foreign key relation in Django+Django REST

Tags: django, rest

I am very new to Python-Django and web dev and I am stuck at this particular issue of creating a new resource using POST.

I am using Django REST framework for REST API and I am trying to create a new resource. THe model has a foreign key relation an I want the related resources to be created in one go. I am posting a sample model, serializer and view so that I am clear in my question.

** My Models has two classes with a many to one relationship.

```
class Carmodel(models.Model):
    modelkey = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    makerkey = models.ForeignKey('Carmaker', db_column='makerkey', related_name='models')
    modelname = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'carmodel'

class Carmaker(models.Model):
    makerkey = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    makername = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

class Meta:
        db_table = 'carmaker'
```

** I have serializer class as below

```
class CarmodelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Carmodel
        fields = ('modelkey','makerkey','modelname')

class CarmakerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    models = CarmodelSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Carmaker
        fields = ('makerkey','makername','models')
```

** The view where I am trying to create the resource looks like

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def carmaker(request, makerkey, format=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CarmakerSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

** My Input looks like this and I want to create the Carmaker resource along with the nested Carmodels.

```
{
    "makerkey": 1, 
    "makername": "lamborghini", 
    "models": [
        {
            "modelkey": 11, 
            "makerkey": 1, 
            "modelname": "reventon" 
        }, 
        {
            "modelkey": 12, 
            "makerkey": 1, 
            "modelname": "aventador" 
        }
    ]
}
```

** I am getting response as

```
{
    "models": [
        {
            "makerkey": [
                "Invalid pk '1' - object does not exist."
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "makerkey": [
                "Invalid pk '1' - object does not exist."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to create this kind of a resource in a single POST request? Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [django rest framework create nested objects "Models" by POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921654/django-rest-framework-create-nested-objects-models-by-post)

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same thing, and from my experience (oddly enough), if you set those keys to point to a "makerkey" that already exists, it will work. Try manually creating Carmaker, point your new "makerkey" to your above example and retry the POST.